# Is $\operatorname{Iso}(E)= E \setminus\operatorname{Der}(E)$ or $\operatorname{Iso}(E)=\operatorname{Cl}(E) \setminus\operatorname{Der}(E)$?

Tags: general-topology

In my lecture notes I have the following property:

$\operatorname{Iso}(E)= E \setminus\operatorname{Der}(E)$ ...(1)

but then I saw in other section, they used

$\operatorname{Iso}(E)=\operatorname{Cl}(E) \setminus\operatorname{Der}(E)$ ...(2) (Cl=closure)

Besides I know, $\operatorname{Cl}(E)=$ disjoint union of $\operatorname{Iso}(E)$ and $\operatorname{Der}(E) $.
So from this, I would say (2) should be the correct one.

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct.

Importantly $E \subset \operatorname{Cl}(E)$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(E) \setminus E \subset \operatorname{Der}(E)$, so any point in $\operatorname{Cl}(E)$ that wasn't already in $E$ itself is removed when we remove $\operatorname{Der}(E)$.  The result is the same either way, whether we start with $E$ or $\operatorname{Cl}(E)$.

---

As a simple example that encompasses the entire situation, just note that $$\{1,2\} \setminus \{2,3\} = \{1,2,3\} \setminus \{2,3\}$$

Comment: How is {1,2,3 } the closure of {1,2}?

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Topology doesn't actually matter for the example, only the basic set operations.  If you want it to be topology more explicitly, we would need to define a topological space. To that end, consider the topology $\tau = \{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{1,2,3\}\}$ on the set $\{1,2,3\}$.  If you set $E = \{1,2\}$, then $\operatorname{Der}(E) = \{2,3\}$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(E) = \{1,2,3\}$

Comment: jeez, you are right, I was looking at {2,3} when I thought that, my bad